# Windows Server Hyper-V guests cannot see each other on network

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server

I have a Hyper-V physical machine along with two standard laptops running within my LAN (connected by an ASUS-RT56U router). The physical server runs Windows Hyper-V Server 2008 R2, with two Windows Server 2008 R2 (full) guest VMs installed and running within.

Both laptops run Windows 7. All OSs are 64-bit.

Opening up *Network* in Windows Explorer on either of the two laptops displays both of the laptops in the LAN fine. However, neither of the guest VMs on the server (nor the host itself) are displayed. Indeed, the guest VMs can not see *each other* in *Network* view either. I can ping all computers (laptops and servers) without problems from within the LAN, but all of the servers are simply not visible from anywhere.

In addition, the *Network Map* screen (accessible via Network and Sharing centre) gives me an error message:

> "An error happened during the mapping process."

And I'm suspecting this *might* have something to do with how LLTP (Link Layer Topology Protocol) is working on the network. Worth noting though is that before my server was on the network, the *Network Map* screen displayed fine (as far as I can remember).

Comment: Is the firewall blocking Windows Print and File services? (Network Map doesn't work here on H-V either, I understand there is a setting that can change this.)

Comment: Afraid not. That's turned on.

Comment: After a bit of playing around, I've got the Network view in Win Explorer working (displaying all servers), but Network Map is still having the same issue...

Comment: @Richard: Any chance you could find out what setting that is to get Hyper-V to let Network Map work?

Comment: It was in an article I read, some configuration change to be made. But I cannot recall any details. Time to spend time with search engines... then you can answer your own question.

Comment: @Richard: TRUST ME, search engines turn up zero about it. Or don't, it's up to you. Don't be rude either way though.

Comment: It may not have been h-v specific, but I seem to recall it was. I have given you *all* the information I have, I am not being rude. A search for "windows enable network map" seems to give the same kind of information.

Comment: Yeah, actually you were being rude. Telling some to "go answer their question" is plain rude. It's not for you to decide.